# NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngStyle' since it isn't a known property of 'button'

Tags: angular

I stumbled upon this error. `[ERROR] NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngStyle' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.`

The code in my button.component.html is `<button  [ngStyle] ="{ 'background-color': color }" class="btn">{{ text }}</button>`
The problem comes from ngStyle, if I use style it works perfectly fine. I read in the documentation and here how to fix this error so I can style with `[ngStyle]`, but every solution was to import `CommonModules` in app.modules.ts. Since I'm using Angular: 17.1.2  I don't have such file.

button.component.ts

```
 import { Component, Input} from '@angular/core'; 
 import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

 @Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
   templateUrl: './button.component.html',
  styleUrl: './button.component.css'
 })
 export class ButtonComponent {
   @Input() text!: string;
  @Input() color!: string;
 }
```

app.component.ts

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
 import { HeaderComponent } from "./components/header/header.component";



@Component({
     selector: 'app-root',
    standalone: true,
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrl: './app.component.css',
    imports: [RouterOutlet, HeaderComponent]
 })
export class AppComponent {

}
```

[image]

Styling with ngStyle and to work

Answer (score 2):

Please import [`CommonModule`](https://angular.io/api/common/CommonModule#:%7E:text=CommonModulelink&text=Exports%20all%20the%20basic%20Angular,with%20the%20CLI%20new%20command.) It is required to be able to use the directive `ngStyle`

> Exports all the basic Angular directives and pipes, such as NgIf, NgForOf, DecimalPipe, and so on. Re-exported by BrowserModule, which is included automatically in the root AppModule when you create a new app with the CLI new command.

```
Import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
....

 @Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
   templateUrl: './button.component.html',
  styleUrl: './button.component.css'
 })
 export class ButtonComponent {
   @Input() text!: string;
  @Input() color!: string;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much I've been missing to add it in imports: [CommonModule], !!!!